# Configure apache in EC2 Instance

Tags: apache, apache2, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-web-services

I added an instance EC2 (ubuntu oneiric) in amazon web services, I added a load balancer for that instance and in add a subdomain in netfirms.com. in the apache of that instance I added and enabled a site with this configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName indicadores.innovacioncolombiaaprende.net
DocumentRoot /var/www/ties/
</VirtualHost>
```

But the domain indicadores.innovacioncolombiaaprende.net doesn't show anything, what part I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a DNS entry setup for that sub-domain? That's my first guess at what could be happening. Configuring apache on EC2 isn't any different than configuring it on a physical server. Sub-domains don't magically appear on the net because of apache configs - they are distinct host names that must be explicitly pointed somewhere via DNS.

When I go to: http://innovacioncolombiaaprende.net (not the sub-domain)

I get:

> It works!11
>
> This is the default web page for this server.
>
> The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

More explanation of DNS propagation, how it works, and why it takes time:

- [Why does a change to my DNS take so long to appear?](https://secure.jabsupport.com/support/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=64&nav=0)
- [What is DNS propagation and why does it take so long?](http://webhosting.devshed.com/c/a/Web-Hosting-Articles/What-is-DNS-propagation-and-why-does-it-take-so-long/)

Comment: I added a CNAME record 'indicadores' pointing to
'ec2-50-19-202-168.compute-1.amazonaws.com' <- this is the instance public dns

Comment: Hm, sounds right. How long ago did you add that CNAME? It can take a long time (up to 48 hours) for it to propagate.

Comment: Could just be timing/propagation delay, not sure. When I try to `ping indicadores.innovacioncolombiaaprende.net` the response is 
`ping: cannot resolve indicadores.innovacioncolombiaaprende.net: Unknown host`

Comment: It may not actually take 48 hours, it's just that it /can/ take 48 hours. I added two links to the end of my answer that help answer the "why" question as far as why it takes time for DNS changes to take effect.